# Background process with Qt

Tags: qt, background-process

I'm working on a daily planner project for my school.
and i wanna use background process to start processing when the app opened.

I googled something and i found QProcess class but i did't really realized how it works and how to use it.

And also i read documentation many times but my main problem is at arguments.

Does anyone can help me?

Any reply appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Please read the [`QProcess` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html).

Comment: I read documentation but my main problem is at arguments
I didn't understand what exactly is the arguments

Comment: When you call a process you can provide arguments, e.g. when you run `dir c:\` in cmd.exe, `c:\` is an argument. `QPorcess` is for running an executable, if your executable doesn't expect any arguments, you don't need to set them.

Comment: You might want to re-think whether you really need another process. Generally, the Qt model is to create a worker thread that does all the background work for you, in order to prevent the main (UI) thread from being blocked.

Comment: thanks guys for your replys

Comment: Here's a good article on how to use QThread: [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads; The Full Explanation](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

Comment: I agree that you probably want to try a different approach however this should help you a little on command line arguments: [https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson14.html](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson14.html)